# Primefaces SelectCheckboxMenu multiple label doesn't appears

Tags: primefaces

I'm trying to implement Primefaces 6.1 SelectCheckboxMenu with `multiple="true"`. But it doesn't shows the label. Even in component given in [SelectCheckboxMenu Showcase](https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/input/checkboxMenu.xhtml), you can remark that it has an empty value for the label

**UPDATE**

code snippet from showCase

```html
    <h:outputLabel for="multiple" value="Multiple:" />
    <p:selectCheckboxMenu id="multiple" 
               value="#{checkboxView.selectedCities2}" label="Cities" 
               multiple="true" filter="true" filterMatchMode="startsWith" 
               panelStyle="width:250px">
        <f:selectItems value="#{checkboxView.cities}" />
    </p:selectCheckboxMenu>
```

error snapshot from showcase

[image]

So, there is no solution to that problem ??

Comment: I see all the labels in the showcase works for me.

Comment: thank you for responding, please see my edit

Comment: Ahhh that label. Might be by design since the ones you select become visible...

Comment: yeah, it would be better to have a label when no choice had been selected, as for the 1st component in the image

Comment: Contrary to the question, it does show selected items. Yes, it shows nothing when nothing is selected. I fail to see the problem. You want an option to show a label when nothing is selected? Create a feature request at the PrimeFaces issue tracker.

Comment: you were right, the person who modify the post alter it (from previous comment we talked about label) I changed it. thank you

Comment: Any solution for this problem